# How to check type on compile time

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c-preprocessor

I'm giving option to compile the program with either float or double type, but there is a problem: I need to manually set either GL_FLOAT or GL_DOUBLE, because I dont know how can I do the following:

```
typedef float MYTYPE;

#if MYTYPE == float
    #define GL_MYTYPE GL_FLOAT // used for vertex array parameters.
#else
    #define GL_MYTYPE GL_DOUBLE
#endif
```

Note: I dont have C++11 or whatsoever, just the good old C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
#define MYFLOAT

#ifdef MYFLOAT
    typedef float MYTYPE;
     #define GL_MYTYPE GL_FLOAT // used for vertex array parameters.
#else
    typedef double MYTYPE;
    #define GL_MYTYPE GL_DOUBLE
#endif
```

You would need to define `MYFLOAT` if you want to use `float`, or omit it to use `double`.

PS: keep in ind this is not evaluated at compile time, but at pre-processing time.

Comment: ah, that makes more sense than checking types.

Answer (score 11):

In C++11, you can use [`std::conditional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional) and [`std::is_same`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same) as:

```
#define GL_MYTYPE  std::conditional                       \
                   <  std::is_same<MYTYPE,float>::value,  \
                      GL_FLOAT,                           \
                      GL_DOUBLE                           \
                   >::type
```

In C++03, you can implement these functionalities yourself as:

```
template<bool B, class T, class F>
struct conditional { typedef T type; };

template<class T, class F>
struct conditional<false, T, F> { typedef F type; };
```

and

```
template<class T, class U>
struct is_same { static const bool value = false; };

template<class T>
struct is_same<T, T> { static const bool value = true; };
```

Note that the implementation of `conditional` is taken from the [site](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional) itself.

Answer (score 2):

`#define`s are processed by the preprocessor, before the compiler runs.  So it doesn't see the `typedef`.

Answer (score 2):

Use preprocessor macros to change what your `typedef` line does

```
#if defined(TYPE_IS_FLOAT)
typedef float MYTYPE;
#else
typedef double MYTYPE;
#end
```

And then use your build system to set `TYPE_IS_FLOAT` as appropriate (and give it a better name of course).

Or wrap all the code which behaves like this up in a template class and use a template parameter for this type, then use whichever version is appropriate at the time.

Answer (score 0):

You may use #ifdef as follow :

```
#ifdef DOUBLE
   #define GL_MYTYPE GL_FLOAT
   //or
   typdef ...
#endif

#ifdef FLOAT
   #define GL_MYTYPE GL_DOUBLE
   //or
   typdef ...
#endif
```

You have to compile your code with DOUBLE or FLOAT as the symblos defined.

Answer (score 0):

I think [Nawaz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10913905/148668) is *nearly* correct. In the special case of choosing between `GL_FLOAT` and `GL_DOUBLE`, `std::conditional` is not needed. Just use a [ternary if](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:):

```
#define GL_MYTYPE std::is_same<MYTYPE,float>::value?GL_FLOAT:GL_DOUBLE
```

This is because `GL_FLOAT` and `GL_DOUBLE` are not types, but rather literal `GLenum` values. So `GL_MYTYPE` should also not be a typename but a `GLenum`. So I'd rather use:

```
const GLenum GL_MYTYPE = std::is_same<MYTYPE,float>::value?GL_FLOAT:GL_DOUBLE;
```